# Attach Shared Object to android process with IDA

Tags: ida, debugging, android, shared-object

I am:

- working with an Android game,
- using an Android Emulator,
- and trying to attach an android `.so` library to a process.

I have the whole IDA server set up, I can attach to processes when a `classes.dex` is loaded into IDA but, when I load the `.so` file and try to attach, I get this message from IDA

> The debugger could not attach to the selected process.
> This can perhaps indicate the process was terminated, or you don't have the necessary privileges.

I see a problem with this because I have full root permission and I know for sure the process was not terminated.

I read [here](https://finn.svbtle.com/error-the-file-cant-be-loaded-by-the-debugger-plugin) that I may have to recompile the entire Android kernel, don't get me wrong, I love wasting hours compiling, but I was just wondering if you guys can help me find something to solve this pesky little situation of mine.

Edit: This may be a dup but the dup wasn't answered and was from 2014. :/

Comment: Could you share / explain what the so is doing?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm not 100% sure what you're saying, but it SOUNDS like you're saying that you load the `.SO` into IDA, and then you're trying to attach to it.

Well, the `.SO` isn't a PROCESS per se.  It's just a library loaded dynamically by something else.  What you probably need to do, is to load the game/application that USES that `.SO`, and set a breakpoint at the location where it calls the function(s) that you're interested in, and then just single step into the `.SO` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
cat /proc/kmsg | grep "Restricted"
```

returns results that are similar to ones in the blog you linked, then indeed `CONFIG_SEC_RESTRICT_FORK` is set and the only way to get rid of it is to recompile the kernel

Comment: I used the command both in ADBs shell and a Terminal emulator app and neither of them returned anything. This is really strange, that's why I asked you guys. Are there any other confounding variables that may be effecting this?